# Checking custom callback in Angular 6 component

Tags: angular, emit

I am using an Angular 2+ wizard component (I'm on Angular 6) that I forked into my project and did a lot of template and styling customizations to. Unfortunately the one I chose doesn't support the canExit functionality found in other wizards, so I am trying to add it. It has the ability to validate the form in the step, so I've usually been able to just add another custom validation function when I need to do more than simple field validation like so:

```
<custom-wizard>
  <wizard-step [title]='Step 1' [isValid]='step1Form.valid && validateStep1()'>
    <form>....
```

The problem is this gets called repeatedly, due to Angular's watching and change detection I assume. Normally that's not a problem but I want to do a server-side validation only once when they hit Next. Having it called repeatedly is a non-starter.

So I figure I needed to pass a callback function as a parameter to the child wizard-step component:

```
<custom-wizard>
  <wizard-step [title]='Step 1' [isValid]='step1Form.valid' [canExit]='validateStep1()'>
    <form>....
```

In the parent component, I created my validation function:

```
validateStep1(){
    console.log('calling server...');
    // assume this is a server-side call, returning true/false
    return serverValidationPassed();
}
```

In the wizard-step component I added:

```
@Input() canExit: boolean = true;
```

In the custom-wizard, I check if this callback fails and if so prevent the normal step change:

```
public next(): void {
    if(!this.activeStep.canExit){
        console.log('failed!');
        return;
    }
    else {
        //proceed to next step as usual
    }
}
```

The problem is the validation is still called many times, I was right back where I started! I read about using an @Output to pass in functions instead, so I tried this approach:

```
<custom-wizard>
  <wizard-step [title]='Step 1' [isValid]='step1Form.valid' (canExit2)='validateStep1()'>
    <form>....
```

And in the wizard-step:

```
    @Output() canExit2: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

And in the wizard's next function:

```
    public next(): void {
    if(!this.activeStep.canExit2.emit()){
        console.log('failed!');
        return;
    }
    else {
        //proceed to next step as usual
    }
}
```

The validate step is only called once now, nice. But even when the validateStep1 passes, I get a failure on the if check. I believe it's because an emit doesn't return anything, but rather broadcasts. This is new territory for me. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here and how I can perform this extra validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem if anyone else ever experiences something similar. My root problem was I was essentially trying to do synchronous server-side checking, but using a template-driven form. I read up on Reactive forms from the Angular docs and that was the ticket- perform a custom validation on a given form field before the form is even considered valid.

Thus I didn't need to mess with the wizard component at all, now that I can mark the form invalid based on the result of a service call. What's even nicer is it only calls the validation once the field meets the form criteria (in my case once the input was the correct length, the additional validation was attempted).

This was a good overview of doing custom async validation, the only thing he missed was you need to import ReactiveFormsModule into your module:

https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/